# Open a 64 Bit COM program in 64 bit python

Tags: python, com

I am building an image processor for astronomical images, and require 64-bit python for alot of the data handling.

Previously the astrometric program I was automating in python (Pinpoint), was 32-bit, so I was running the code to use that in 32 bit python, using win32com, and running the image processer in a 64 bit python environment seperately.

They recently came out with a 64 bit version so I want to integrate it into my 64 python env code, but keep running into errors.

```
import win32com
f = win32com.client.Dispatch("Pinpoint.plate")
```

This was the code that ran fine in 32-bit python, because the program itself(pinpoint) was 32 bit. However running this in 64-bit python, I get the following error

```
  File "C:\Users\shane\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)

com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)
```

Is there a win64com for running 64 bit programs?

Comment: First step in diagnosing this is to write a VB script file: `set obj = CreateObject("pinpoint.plate")` next line is `MsgBox TypeName(obj)` although you could probably drop it. The first line is the diagnostic really. Put code in a .vbs file and try to execute it. Since you say everything is 64-bit, you should be able to just double click on file in Explorer or from cmd.exe type: `wscript \path\to\your\script.vbs`. This will at least verify outside of Python whether the object can be instantiated. That you are getting the error you are, this might fail in the same way...registration issue.

Comment: Tested that and the object does not open. Gave a runtime error saying that ActiveX component can not create object. Weird that it works perfectly fine in 32-bit python.

Comment: you can test it in 32-bit VB script as well.  `c:\windows\syswow64\wscript.exe \path\to\your\vbscript.vbs`

Comment: And you say program to describe the "COM program". I assume that means an .EXE ? Instantiating COM objects implemented as DLLs is different than ones implemented as EXEs. ... especially in regards to mixing 32 and 64 bit modules.